# IQuery is not running as expected

Tags: c#, hibernate

i have the Following Method:

```
ServiceType GetWithValidServices(long ServiceTypeID);
```

and the following Function:

```
public ServiceType GetWithValidServices(long ServiceTypeID)
    {
        IQuery query = CurrentSession.CreateQuery("select dl.ServiceType from Service as dl"
         + "where dl.ServiceType.ID = :id and dl.IsValid = true"
         + "order by dl.HavePriority desc");

        query.SetInt64("id", ServiceTypeID);

        var dlArt = query.UniqueResult<ServiceType>();
        return dlArt;
    }
```

In the following Method i call the the above mentioned function:

```
 public ServiceCollection GetService(long ServiceTypeID)
    {

        ServiceType d = DomainToWebgridMapper.GetWebgridServiceType(DaoFactory.Instance.ServiceTypeDao.GetWithValidService(ServiceTypeID));

        return d.Service;
    }
```

My Problem is that the query is not running correctly. I can see the Services but the filter where dl.IsValid is not running, also he do not order the Types by Priority.

I use the where-clause in few other Methods and there it is working fine.

I don't know what is going wrong here. Maybe someone can help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what your problem is; it has to do with how you're concatenating the strings to create the query. Consider this for a moment:

```
string query = "select dl.ServiceType from Service as dl"
     + "where dl.ServiceType.ID = :id and dl.IsValid = true"
     + "order by dl.HavePriority desc";
```

Because you're not inserting any spaces or line breaks at the beginnings/ends of your strings, what your query turns into is this:

```
select dl.ServiceType from Service as dlwhere dl.ServiceType.ID = :id and dl.IsValid = trueorder by dl.HavePriority desc
                                      ^^^^^^^                                          ^^^^^^^^^
```

See where I've marked the problems? To remedy this, add an extra space to the end of all but the last string you're concatenating to make up the query, or use something like a [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) instead.

```
IQuery query = CurrentSession.CreateQuery(
    "select dl.ServiceType from Service as dl " +
    "where dl.ServiceType.ID = :id and dl.IsValid = true " +
    "order by dl.HavePriority desc"
);
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried that already, but the query is still not running correctly